# Batch File Windows 10 won't execute

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch files. My Professor has written custom software for Autodesk Maya and the program works on most student's computers; however, not on mine. We all have windows 10 and my computer is brand new. The .bat simply open and closes. I add 'Pause' to the last line to see the window stay open and see 'access is denied'; or, when I run as an administrator, it does nothing. This is confusing as the .bat file is only updating the directory of the plugin. I know there are a plethora of reasons for this, but I would appreciate a heads up. 
Thank you.

```
@echo off

set CURR_DIR=%~dp0
set BDMOVE_MOD_FILE=%CURR_DIR%\BDMove.mod
set MAYA_ENV_FILE=%CURR_DIR%\Maya.env

echo + BDMove VERSION %CURR_DIR% > %BDMOVE_MOD_FILE%

echo ^# BDMove Environment Variables > %MAYA_ENV_FILE%
echo. >> %MAYA_ENV_FILE%

echo # Change the following line to reflect your installation >> %MAYA_ENV_FILE%
echo BDMOVE_PATH=%CURR_DIR% >> %MAYA_ENV_FILE%

echo. >> %MAYA_ENV_FILE%
echo MAYA_MODULE_PATH=%%MAYA_MODULE_PATH%%;%%BDMOVE_PATH%% >> %MAYA_ENV_FILE%
echo MAYA_SHELF_PATH=%%MAYA_SHELF_PATH%%;%%BDMOVE_PATH%%\shelves >> %MAYA_ENV_FILE%
echo PATH=%%PATH%%;%%BDMOVE_PATH%%\bin >> %MAYA_ENV_FILE%
Pause
```

Comment: If you are getting "Access Denied" then it is generally one of two things: 1)You don't have the proper privilege, or 2)Whatever you are trying to access does not exist at the path you gave. Send your output to a file and then paste that here. Also make sure to try doing what you are doing in the batch file by hand. If the path is correct and the files are where they should be, then you may have to run the batch file as an administrator.

Comment: the first lines assume the .BAT reside in the same directory of the MOD and ENV files. Check that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have checked all of the .dll files and others to make sure that they are unblocked (not sure if this makes a difference). I am not sure how to batch the file by hand? I have tried running as an administrator. My professor suggested this, but he said it doesn't work on all computers. I cannot properly read the file to understand that it is supposed to write two files.

Comment: @PA yes I checked and they are located in the same folder.

Comment: What do you mean under "it does nothing"? If the files aren't created, make sure current dir is not right  protected. In Admin Cmd Prompt, run the string: `cd %~dp0 & echo Hello > test.txt` , then check the file _test.txt_ .

Comment: I'd try `> "%BDMOVE_MOD_FILE%"` and  `>> "%MAYA_ENV_FILE%"` etc. Note double quotes.

Comment: @sambul35 `%~dp0` has no effect on command line (works only in batchfiles), `cd %~dp0` resulting in "path not found"

Comment: Thanks Stephan. Open Admin Cmd Prompt in your target dir, run the string: `echo Hello > test.txt` , then check the file `test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
In my case, the folder containing the cmd file and the output log was copied from another computer.
The output log file had to be deleted first in order to run the command (even if is recreated/overwritten each time I run the cmd and even if it was on Desktop).

Comment: Are you sure that you have the exact setup as the OP does so you know how to solve it? Do you have the exact hardware, software, settings, folder structure?